# Access Operator field from NodeSelectorTerms of a pod

Tags: go, kubernetes

For context, suppose the /spec/affinity part of my pod object looks like:

```
Value: corev1.Affinity{
            NodeAffinity: &corev1.NodeAffinity{
                RequiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution: &corev1.NodeSelector{
                    NodeSelectorTerms: []corev1.NodeSelectorTerm{{
                        MatchExpressions: []corev1.NodeSelectorRequirement{{
                            Key:      "Hello",
                            Operator: "DoesNotExist",
                        }},
                    }},
                },
            },
        },
```

Now I am working on a function which will fetch this Operator: "DoesNotExist" from a coreV1.Pod object and return a string. This is what I have come up with so far :

```
func (k *kubernetesClient) checkOD(namespace string, replicasetName string, podName string, asyncOD chan bool) error{
    var ownerRef []metav1.OwnerReference
    result, err := k.kubeClient.CoreV1().Pods(namespace).Get(context.TODO(), podName, metav1.GetOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Error(err)
        return  err
    }
    var val corev1.NodeSelectorOperator
    ms.MatchExpressions.Operator 
    ownerRef = result.OwnerReferences
    for _, item := range ownerRef{
        if item.Name == replicasetName{
            val = result.Spec.Affinity.NodeAffinity.RequiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.NodeSelectorTerms.MatchExpressions.Operator 
        }
    }

}
```

However, when I am trying to assign the Operator field of a pod to the val variable, it gives an error saying:
NodeSelectorTerms doesn't have a field or a method called MatchExpressions. However, in the documentation it is pretty clear that the struc has a field.
Reference: https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api@v0.20.1/core/v1?utm_source=gopls#NodeSelectorTerm

Can anyone help me in pointing out what's wrong with my approach, is the method through which I am trying to access the Operator field incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue some time ago.
NodeSelectorTerm is a custom slice type so you can iterate over its items.

```
for _, el := range result.Spec.NodeAffinity.Required.NodeSelectorTerms[0].MatchExpressions {
    if el.Key == "foo" {
        val = el.Operator
    }
}
```

Note the presence of `[0]` in `NodeSelectorTerms[0]`, without it you won't be able to get `MatchExpressions`.
It looks like client-go has one item list in which there are `MatchExpressions` and `MatchFields` slice objects.